# Html table cells not responsive on iphone emails

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, html-email

I'm setting up an html template for a client so having fun with tables, yay.

Responsiveness previews correctly in desktop browser, but when sent to an iphone, the td's are not scaling with the percentage applied, just defaulting to content size. The example I've supplied is for images (trying to setup a nav for the template), but also applies to text only as well.

The goal is a 600px centered content area with the background of the email a light gray. Under 600px, the nav cells should responsively scale to 25% of the viewport, but with text content the cells shrink to text size, and images they expand to image size.

Anyone know a way on iphones to set table cell widths as a percentage of the viewport?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
        <style>
            .wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #ebebeb;
            }
            .container {
                width: 600px;
                max-width: 600px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            .header {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                width: 100%;
            }
            @media (max-width: 600px) {
                html, body, .wrapper, .container, .header, .wrapper-td, .container-td {
                    width: 100% !important;
                    max-width: 100% !important;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="wrapper">
            <tr>
                <td class="wrapper-td">
                    <table class="container">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="container-td">
                                <table class="header">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 25%;">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/a3mogw58b/nav_membership.jpg" style="width: 100%;" /></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 25%;">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/a3mogw58b/nav_membership.jpg" style="width: 100%;" /></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 25%;">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/a3mogw58b/nav_membership.jpg" style="width: 100%;" /></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 25%;">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/a3mogw58b/nav_membership.jpg" style="width: 100%;" /></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. So you want 4 boxes (25% witdh) on desktop in a 600px frame with gray background, and on iphone you want them to be 100% under eachother?

Comment: actually, under 600px viewport, I'm trying to get the 4 TD's to responsively scale to 25% (not the best UI, I know, but those are the requirements)

Comment: Have you tried my answer below? I could make it work

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `html, body{margin:0; padding:0}` to the style, and `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` to all your tables.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/Bidstrup/pen/LVobpG